# Jmeter: how to encode(utf8) a string and send as payload in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

i want to encode a string using UTF 8 and pass the encoded value as part of payload in a post request.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Guide to Character Encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding) in Java if encoding is not specified explicitly it falls back to the platform default encoding.

So the easiest would be just setting [`file.encoding`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding) Java system property to `UTF-8`, it can be done in *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the properly. More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Additionally you can specify the request encoding in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults))

[image]

Comment: still didn't work, is there any other way to encode the string to utf-8  using any preprocessor or function